# Prevent from route change in AngularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {

            var partsOfUrl = next.split('/');
            var isLogin = false;
            if(partsOfUrl.indexOf("signin") > 0) {
                isLogin = true;
            }

            var myDataPromise = loginService.getData();

            myDataPromise.then(function(data) {  // this is only run after $http completes
                if(!isLogin) {
                    if(data.logout) {
                        $location.url("pages/signin");
                        event.preventDefault();
                    } else{}
                } else {
                    if(data.logout) {
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            });
            console.log(next);

        });
```

This is the code i used to check user authentication and prevent the protected areas. But problem here is if a user try to access protected then immediately browser shows the secure page and then get back to login page instead of redirecting to login page first. I think that's because of user authentication process is done through an Ajax call so the program never holds for the response. What's the wrong here and how should i get rid of it ?

Comment: Try with httpInterceptor https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with httpInterceptor (from mean.io stack)
btw the server should response with a 401 status

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mean-factory-interceptor',[])
    .factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q','$location',function ($q,$location) {
        return {
            'response': function(response) {
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    $location.path('/signin');
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },

            'responseError': function(rejection) {

                if (rejection.status === 401) {
                    $location.url('/signin');
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }

        };
    }
    ])
    //Http Intercpetor to check auth failures for xhr requests
    .config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
    }]);
```